Yocto | Poky | Dunfell | ARM | Java 17 | Segmentation fault
Good afternoon, everyone, I’m trying to update a Yocto layer, that was working with Java-8 and it’s required to update to Java-17.
The device that I’m trying to flash it’s an arm7 (arm on poky) and the rootfs it’s readonly, but after flash I’m getting the following errors:
The current version that I have, uses the following version of ‘meta-java’:
https://github.com/meta-java/meta-java/tree/e122acf3e9570ceb055e55feb41e5558463253e4
But I need to update to Java-17, I tried the following 2 Repos:
https://github.com/bobolopolis/meta-adoptium
This one, was able to run properly and make the installation and references, but there’s a problem when trying to run java, when I run just ‘java’ command on the image flashed on a device and run java and java -jar commands and I got:

Segmentation Fault
I'm pretty sure that's something the untar process, since the error it's being sent from java.
If I copy the tarball untar on the device and run java command, it run java without any issues.
Also tried to add on layer.conf
# Java arm configuration
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-initial-native = "cacao-initial-native"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-initial = "cacao-initial"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-native = "cacao-native"

And a custom copy process to give permissions, but still have the error:
do_install() {
  install -d ${D}${JAVA_HOME}
  install -d -m 0755 ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/bin
  install -d -m 0755 ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/lib
  install -d -m 0644 ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/conf
  install -d -m 0644 ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/legal
  #install -d -m ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/bin
  #install -d -m ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/lib
  #install -d -m ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/conf
  #install -d -m ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/legal

  # Copy sources to the final image
  cp -r ${S}/bin/*   ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/bin
  cp -r ${S}/lib/*   ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/lib
  cp -r ${S}/conf/*  ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/conf
  cp -r ${S}/legal/* ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/legal
  cp    ${S}/NOTICE  ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/NOTICE
  cp    ${S}/release ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/release

  # Give permissions to binaries and libraries
  chmod --recursive +x ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/bin
  chmod --recursive +x ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/bin
  chmod --recursive +x ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/lib
}

Also tried this one:
https://github.com/lucimber/meta-openjdk-temurin
But it gave me a lot of errors on the build time, and not able to generate a build, maybe it’s because it doesn’t support Dunfell.
I have another layers that do the same like .NET 8, and run without issues, and the paths are almost the same.
UPDATE 2024-07-31
As an update, I was able to verify that when performing the decompression on the yocto server and copying the files to the IoT device, I got the error "Segmentation Fault".
However, using this command on the server:
gunzip -c ${THISDIR}/files/java.tar.gz | tar xopf -
And then copying the files, giving execution permissions, I was able to run java.
Now, after making this change I replaced the do_unpack process, as follows:
do_unpack() {
  # Unpack the tarball
  gunzip -c ${THISDIR}/files/OpenJDK17U- 
 jre_arm_linux_hotspot_17.0.12_7.tar.gz | tar xopf -
}

After making this change, I proceeded to do the following test, I added to the recipe in addition to unzipping and copying to the image:
cp -r ${S}/* ${D}${JAVA_HOME}
I added a copy from the image to the yocto server
cp -r ${D}${JAVA_HOME}/* /home/ubuntu/meta-java-results
Then, I copied this folder to the IoT device and after giving it execution permissions it worked without problems.
However, in the .wic image, when flashing the device and running the java command I still get the segmentation fault error.
So I think the problem is no longer with the do_unpack process or the cp -r ${S}/* ${D}${JAVA_HOME} copy, but I'm not sure which process could be causing the problem.
Update 2023-08-02
Good morning
I have a new finding, but not the solution yet, however, maybe I can help to identify which step is causing this error.
I made a change on the do_install function in the recipe to do the following:
do_install() {
  # First install the directory '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17-jre'
  install -d ${D}${libdir_jre}

  # Then create a directory '/home/java'
  mkdir -p ${D}/home/java

  # Now copy the files from the tarball to '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17-jre'
  cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${S}/* ${D}${libdir_jre}

  # Then copy the files from the  '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17-jre' to '/home/java'
  cp -R --no-dereference --preserve=mode,links -v ${D}${libdir_jre}/* ${D}/home/java
}

After build the recipe and flash the image on the device.
If i run the commands:
$ /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17-jre/bin/java
# I get a 'segmentation fault'

$ /home/java/bin/java
# I get the proper output

From what I can conclude, the problem is not with the tarball files or with the files copied to the image, it is a post process that is applied only to the directory in ${libdir}/jvm/openjdk-17-jre i.e. /usr/lib/jvm
